# How do I get VS Code to recognize 'constexpr'?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

When I use `constexpr`, VS Code gives me the error: "unknown name type 'constexpr'". I did some research about constexpr on osx and found that I'd need to compile with `-std=c++11`. But my issue isn't with compiling, it's simply getting the text editor to recognize `constexpr` as a valid keyword. Is there something I need to `#include` in order to get this to be valid?

How do I get VS Code to not give me an error on `constexpr`?

Comment: This is a problem with your editor not fully understanding the C++11 language syntax. You may be able to add constexpr to the keywords list in VSC, but I don't use it, so I have no guidance for that.

Comment: Did you install the [Microsoft C/C++ Extension for VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) (or maybe some other extension, I don't use VS Code)?

Comment: @jwdonahue VS Code is new enough that it should definitely have a built-in option to work with C++11 (I think it was only started as a project after 2011), but I don't know what it is.

Comment: What version of the standard did you set in your `c_cpp_properties.json` file? VS Code on my machine has no problem with `constexpr`

Comment: VS code is just plain new and unstable. Originally didn't have any support at all for non-typescript programming languages. I was there when it was a Microsoft internal tool. I wouldn't assume that its intellisense engine is entirely capable yet, but I don't actually know. It does seem like an editor configuration issue however.

Comment: @UnholySheep 
I believe this is the information you mentioned    
       "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64".

And it seems like I'm using the most recent version c++17, which should include c++11, unless Im understanding it wrong.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed look correct. It's strange, it's working fine on my machine. Maybe you should create a bug report on the official VS Code Cpptools bug tracker (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues), they might be able to help better

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the Microsoft [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension installed, the problem is most likely that it is using the wrong C++ standard.  [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) was introduced in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (meaning the 2011 standard), so that is the minimum required; C++98 and C++03 will not work.

To tell VSCode which standard to use, go to the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type "C/C++: Edit Configurations" and press Enter.  Scroll down to "C++ standard" and choose "C++11" (or higher) from the dropdown:

[image: C++ language selector dropdown]

Then it should recognize `constexpr` as a keyword.

If that does not work, or if you run into other problems, I recommend going through the VSCode [Getting Started with C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) tutorial since that will get you a working configuration to start from.

Also, check the output of the "C/C++: Log Diagnostics" command (in the palette).  That will report a variety of details about how VSCode thinks it is configured for C++.